# Why am I getting this array to string conversion error?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im trying to take the first element in an array and insert it into mysql or, if the array is empty, display a message saying the info is unknown. I keep getting this array to string error and its not updating mysql. Here's what I have

```
$phone_number_parser = preg_match_all("/([0-9]?[- .(]*[0-9]{3}[- .)][0-9]{3}[- .][0-9]{4})/", $result['adtext'], $phone_number);

    var_dump($phone_number[0]); 
    //go to the next row
    if (empty($phone_number))
    {
    $query2 = "UPDATE usedcars SET phonenumber = 'UNKNOWN' WHERE `key` = $x";
    echo "<font  color='#FF0000'>PHONE NUMBER UNKNOWN</font><br>";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    }
    else
    {

    $query3 = "UPDATE usedcars SET phonenumber = ('$phone_number[0]') WHERE `key` = $x";
     echo "<font  color='#00FF00'>INSERTING NUMBER $phone_number[0] INTO DATABASE</font><br>";
     mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
     }

    $x++;
    }
```

not only am I getting this error and not updating mysql values, the display message is showing the `echo` from query3 whether the array is empty or not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This guy @Riad is a beast(euphemism for awesome coder) who held my little newb hand and walked me though my code. MUCH RESPECT AND THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing wrong values.

```
var_dump($phone_number[0]); 
//go to the next row
if (is_array($phone_number[0]) && count($phone_number[0]) == 0)  // check if an array...
{
   //..codes goes here...
}
else
{

    $query3 = "UPDATE usedcars SET phonenumber = (' ".$phone_number[0][0]." ') WHERE `key` = $x";
    echo "<font  color='#00FF00'>INSERTING NUMBER $phone_number[0][0] INTO DATABASE</font><br>";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
 }
```

Comment: That fixed the display strings but Im still getting the error and mysql still not updating @Riad

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in...and these are the lines $query3 = "UPDATE usedcars SET phonenumber = ('$phone_number[0]') WHERE `key` = $x";
     echo "<font  color='#00FF00'>INSERTING NUMBER $phone_number[0] INTO DATABASE</font><br>";
     mysqli_query($conn, $query3); @Riad

Comment: try to echo $query3 ..and see the result... also what does var_dum($phone_number[0]) shows?

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\blahblah\usedcarnumberextractor.php on line 65
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0156 249056 {main}( ) ..\usedcarnumberextractor.php:0
INSERTING NUMBER Array INTO DATABASE
array (size=0)
  empty
PHONE NUMBER UNKNOWN
array (size=0)
  empty
PHONE NUMBER UNKNOWN
array (size=1)
  0 => string '-347-637-8795' (length=13) this a sample. Btw, as you can see sometimes it will show the NUMBER UNKNOWN string even when the array contains a phone number. How did that happen? @Riad

Comment: paste the echo $query3 output...and append the result of var_dump($phone_number[0]) to the question

Comment: Also, when it shows the echo for query3 it says "INSERTING NUMBER Array INTO DATABASE" instead of actually showing the number. @Riad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65026/discussion-between-riad-and-tommyg).